# How to output a live JSON feed in Python 3?

Tags: python, json

I am using Python 3 to access a live JSON feed from http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.geojson. This is the code:

```
try:
    # For Py 3.0+
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    # For Py 2
    from urllib2 import urlopen

import json

def printResults(data):
  # Use the json module to load the string data into a dictionary
  theJSON = json.loads(data) #pass JSON data into a dictionary

  # now we can access the contents of the JSON like any other Python object
  if "title" in theJSON["metadata"]:
    print (theJSON["metadata"]["title"])

def main():
  # JSON feed of earthquake activity larger than 2.5 in the past 25 hours
  urlData = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.geojson"

  #open url and read contents
  webUrl = urlopen(urlData)
  print (webUrl.getcode())
  if (webUrl.getcode() == 200):
    data = webUrl.read()
    #print results
    printResults(data)

  else:
    print ("Received an error from server " + str(webUrl.getcode()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 420, in run_nodebug
  File "C:\Users\modar\Desktop\jsondata_finished.py", line 56, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\modar\Desktop\jsondata_finished.py", line 50, in main
    else:
  File "C:\Users\modar\jsondata_finished.py", line 13, in printResults
    if "title" in theJSON["metadata"]:
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\decoder.py", line 352, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

How can I fix this? An explanation as to what went wrong would also be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library or [human_curl](https://github.com/Lispython/human_curl).

Comment: @hd1 thanks for that. But why am I getting that error?

Comment: Unsure, I was just giving it as a comment.

Comment: Can you give us the full stacktrace?

Comment: @VincentBeltman it was just that one error. The code seems to be working fine for the guy doing the video tutorial. He was using Python 2.7. I am using Python 3. I am not sure what to change to get it to work in Python 3.

Comment: The error gives you a linenumber. That will help alot

Comment: @VincentBeltman I just updated the question with the full error. I hope that would be more meaningful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the requests library, linked to in my comment above, your code becomes:

```
quake_data = requests.get('http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.geojson').json()
print(quake_data['metadata']['title'])
```

I do hope it helps...